# Socket.IO keeps reconnecting Websocket on Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, cloudflare

I have a Node/Express app on server dedicated to sockets and on the client it's Angular 1.5. Running the code locally on http using the same architecture e.g. separate socket server it all works perfectly fine.

When I run the code locally it creates one connection and does very little polling via xhr. On cloudflare with https it does a lot of polling, reconnects continually and not all the messages seem to be getting to the web client

messages hit cloudflare which then redirects them to a loadbalancer running haproxy which then routes the requests to an app running in a docker instance on another machine.

[image: Websocket connections]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation I found the issue to be down to the config in haproxy. I needed to alter the timeouts around the socket routing.

This was nothing to do with ports not being open on cloudflare.

The following link helped me
http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/11/07/websockets-load-balancing-with-haproxy/

Answer (score 0):

Your Issue is most likely occuring beacause of an issue with cloudflare only allowing traffic to a limited set of ports. Try one of the ports listed in the below link for your server and try connecting to it.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-

Comment: Consider adding answer limited to external links on the comment of the question.